# Why does getActiveRange() not work and are there alternatives?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

When I try to invoke the sheet.getActiveRange() function it does not return a range that represents the currently selected cells of the sheet I am using.  Instead it usually thinks that the active range is cell(1, 1) but that is not true.  The function worked for a few minutes after not working but as since reverted to the same problem.  This issue seems documented here[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54032056/getactiverange-not-returning-current-selection) but there was no answer so I'm bumping the issue again.

I've tried using activate() on getActiveRange() but it only changes my on-screen selection to cell(1, 1) which clearly illustrates the problem.

```
var rng = master.getActiveRange();
Logger.log(rng.getHeight());
```

Hypothetically the selected range could have a height of 5 or whatever but it always comes back as one because cell(1, 1) has a height of one.  Basically it just always thinks the active range is cell(1, 1).

Comment: What's the rest of the code? Where is master defined?

Answer (score 1):

I was testing this and I kept having the same behavior you are, turns out if you're using `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()` after some time you need to "update" it. To do this you simply need to go to the sheet and open the script editor from **tools -> script editor** and when you run the code then it will be updated.

Additionally, I ran my test using the [Selection class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/selection#getActiveRange()), which offers a good example on how to manage it.

For a quick test, you can use the following code:

```
function selection(){
  var selection = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSelection();
  var activeRange = selection.getActiveRange();
  Logger.log("Active Cell: " + selection.getCurrentCell().getA1Notation())
  Logger.log("Range: " + activeRange.activate().getA1Notation());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will get the active ranges on the active sheet.

```
function runOne() {
  var rl=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRangeList().getRanges();
  var ls='';
  for(var i=0;i<rl.length;i++) {
    if(i>0) {
      ls+=', ';
    }
    ls+=Utilities.formatString('\'%s\'!%s',rl[i].getSheet().getName(),rl[i].getA1Notation());
  }
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(ls);
}
```